# Route domain.com/api to a specific port using Apache and a Reverse Proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, api, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a Node.js application using Express.js running on port 1399 offering a rest API for the user. The API can be accessed using http://example.com:1399. I'm using Let's Encrypt for SSL.

The problem is that only requests **without SSL** work as Let's Encrypt only allows HTTPS on default ports (such as port 443). Using https://example.com:1399/ (with https) gives me a *Secure connection failed* error on Firefox.

To be able to also offer SSL on other ports than port 443, I would like to route all requests from https://example.com/api to https://example.com:1399/api. How can you do so using Apache and a reverse proxy?

I've tried the solution suggested in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/832206) answer by adding the following in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf:

```
<Virtual Host *:443>
    ...
    ProxyPass /api/ https://127.0.0.1:1399/api/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ https://127.0.0.1:1399/api/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when calling https://example.com/api/ it gives me an *Internal Server Error*. Calling it with http:// gives me no response and will make the loading tab timeout after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

1. Add these two lines to **`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`** right before `</VirtualHost>`:

```
ProxyPass        "/api"  "http://example.com:1399/"
ProxyPassReverse "/api"  "http://example.com:1399/"
```

2. Enable *mod_proxy* and *mod_proxy_http*:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

3. Restart apache2:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```